# Coursera - Functional Programming Principles in Scala - can't work with example project because of errors

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

From that course
https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/assignment

i downloaded
http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/progfun/assignments/example.zip

Imported this to Intellij Idea.

But the problem is to verify code, because in course they running sbt in console...

After run "sbt" in console i get:

```
D:\learning\example>sbt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from D:\learning\example\project\project
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.cl
ass)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1501)
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

I created new project in Intellij Idea with SBT and it works... but version of SBT is other then in example project. But when i changing version of SBT to newest i get dependency errors... I stack and can't move... How to solve situation like that?

I guess i can try move all project to Java8 or force sbt in my console to works with Java7. I don't know how to do both :)

Comment: isn't the courseras forum a better place for this?

Comment: No Java 8 support - please see [this post on the Course forum](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/forum/thread?thread_id=39). Downgrade to Java 7.

Comment: Wow... i am moving from PHP so i have so many things to focus on, so i didnt even realize there is a forum.... with answer :/ Sorry.

But why ```sbt -java-home C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60``` still running sbt with Java8? How to run sbt with Java7?

Comment: If you don't understand how SBT works then just uninstall Java 8 and install Java 7.

Comment: But i want learn that :) Shortcuts are bad in long perspective of time.

Comment: Hmm so mayby it changes the JDK for project not SBT themeself... ? It has sense if that's true.

Comment: But this post https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/forum/thread?thread_id=39#post-932 suggest something else...

Comment: Ok i found there is no option like -java-home and anything similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're getting this issue because Scala prior 2.10.4 doesn't support JDK8. There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1399) describing the problem. You have to downgrade to Java 7.

If you're running sbt on Linux you can set the `-java-home` parameter.

```
  $ sbt -help
  # java version (default: java from PATH, currently java version "1.7.0_60")
  -java-home <path>         alternate JAVA_HOME
```

On Windows however it's not that easy.

Sbt uses `sbt.bat` to run sbt on Windows. You can find it by writing `where sbt` in windows console.

```
C:\Users\lpiepiora>where sbt
C:\Program Files\sbt\bin\sbt
C:\Program Files\sbt\bin\sbt.bat
```

Now you can edit `C:\Program Files\sbt\bin\sbt.bat` and at the beginning of the file just after

```
@REM SBT launcher script
@REM 
@REM Envioronment:
@REM JAVA_HOME - location of a JDK home dir (mandatory)
@REM SBT_OPTS  - JVM options (optional)
@REM Configuration:
@REM sbtconfig.txt found in the SBT_HOME.
```

add

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\...<path to your Java 7>"
```

If you're running sbt, restart it. Confirm the version you're running by typing `about` in the sbt command line.

Answer (score 0):

I use windows and this command in git shell(http://msysgit.github.io/) works for me:

sbt -java-home "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7"

Of course besides jdk8 you have to install jdk7 (I have installed it in path as above).